# create sql azure database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a relatively large database that contains about 1300 tables, more than 3000 stored procedures, and some tables have triggers.

I generated a script for the database, connected to SQL Azure using Sql Server Management Studio and now I am running the script, but it is taking long time to complete (about 3 hours). Is this a normal thing, what can I do to make this process faster?

Comment: that doesn't sound right - can you perform a simple select and see how the execution time compares with the same query on a local DB, just rule out network latency?

Comment: Are you loading some data as well as part of your script?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at breaking the script up to determine what part of the process is taking the time.

Try batching the table creation down and timing the process and then the SPs.